# Django oscar Api is not setting status in OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

I am using django oscar API, and my question is on creating an order using the /checkout/ api method, the order is created but the status is not taken from my OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE it just sets it to 'new'.

In my settings.py file:

```
OSCAR_INITIAL_ORDER_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_INITIAL_LINE_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE = {
'Pending': ('Processing', 'Cancelled',),
'Processing': ('Shipped', 'Cancelled',),
'Shipped': ('Delivered', 'Returned', 'Cancelled',),
'Returned': (),
'Delivered': (),
'Cancelled': (),
}

OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_CASCADE = {
'Processing': 'In progress',
'Shipped': 'Shipped',
'Delivered': 'Delivered',
'Returned': 'Returned',
'Cancelled': 'Cancelled'  
}
```

The initial line status is set correctly to Pending, the problem is only in the order status.Is there some settings that I am missing?

Comment: That's because django-oscar-api [needs](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/serializers/checkout.py#L218) a `OSCARAPI_INITIAL_ORDER_STATUS = 'Pending'` setting as well.

Comment: thanks man it works.